# App is not running on iPod 4.1.1 Says "Finish Running"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod

App is not running on iPod 4.1.1 Says "Finish Running".
Even app runs on iPad 5.0. Why ?

Architecture in the target properties was set to Standard (armv7). I had to add the armv6 architecture and it worked

My xcode ver is 4.2.1

Any suggestion ?

Comment: switched of your iPod and then try again .... and be sure there should not be any other app with same provisioning profile.

Comment: Hi Vakul Sani, I tried but not running app. Even I do not have same provisioning profile.